# couting number of files in git repository

Tags: git, git-remote

Is there any possibility to count number of file in a git remote reposity without cloning them? In CVS we will use

```
cvs rls -lR $OldSrc $ProjectName'"  | grep -v -e '^\$' -e '$ProjectName' -e '^d' | wc -l
```

Where ,

```
    OldSrc --> Tag name [optional]
    ProjectName --> Actual project repository name.
```

Kindly tell me the convenient command in git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that remotely. You have to either clone the git repository or ssh to the remote machine to look at the repository.

Once you have a repository, you can list the files with, for example,

```
git show master^{tree}
```

You can replace `master` with the name of the branch/commit you are interested in. This command works also for bare repositories.

Comment: @opqdonut I think a better option would be `git ls-files | wc -l`. Still doesn't work against a remote repository, but it does recurse through subdirectories, and there are options to affect whether untracked files, modified files, etc. are included or not.

Comment: `ls-files` only works with non-bare repositories. But yeah, my bad for not noticing that `git show` is non-recursive.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use Git for this, I'd use `find`. From the root of a Git working copy, run the following:

```
find * -type f | wc -l
```

Comment: @twalberg: Good spot. Fixed that!

Comment: I want to count the files from remote local machine.

Comment: This will report too high a number. E.g. for a C project, if the source and build tree are the same, we will get a lot of `*.o`, `*.d`, `*.a`, `*.so` (assuming UNIX-like platform) and compiled program files etc; the editor might leave back up files, etc...

Also if there are files in the root directory beginning with `.`, these will be ignored.

This solution to me looks inadequate.